# Ion channels affected by gravity

Tags: neurophysiology, cell-membrane, electrophysiology

In the literature I have found that action potentials behave differently when gravity is changed (cannot access fully).

Action potential properties are gravity dependent. 
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02870977

Are there any ion channels in the neurons that are more or less likely to be sensitive to changes in gravity?

Comment: Please link to the article abstract about gravity.

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02870977Action potential properties are gravity dependent

Comment: I'd say this is a fairly niche area of research so it's unlikely this has been studied beyond the citations you will find in that article.